# Batch script for the below requirement

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
@echo off 
set pathname="C:\folder1\folder2\folder3\bin"
cmd.exe /K cd %pathname%
```

I want to create a bat file which can run the below command with following parameters at the path mentioned above

```
    tools -user %1 -password %2 -server <<URL>>   -maintenance
```

how do I create the batch file where %1 is username %2 is password and the URL is the link
and the tools is batch file within bin folder

Comment: Where do you expect username and password to come from? The logged on user? You can probably get the username, but definitely not the password.

Comment: This will be keyed in at the promt

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all you're looking for is:

```
@echo off
cd "c:\folder1\folder2\folder3\bin"
call tools -user %1 -password %2 -server <<URL>> -maintenance
```

Comment: Where you have %s it should be %2

Comment: You might want to write 'cd /d "c:\xyzdir"' to make sure that the script also works when started from another drive than from C: